# Using openssl command line tool to encrypt/decrypt data, DES ECB

Tags: cryptography, openssl

How can I create a random 64 bit key for DEC ECB encryption/decryption, and then use the same key for encryption/decryption many times? All this must be done using openssl command line tool.

In all the examples I have seen, they do not use a "key", they use "password".
But I need a key - array of bytes - because I need to send it to the other party (I don't know which API they use for cryptography.)

Then I need to use this key - array of bytes - to encrypt/decrypt data.

Thnak you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a `-K 0123456789abcdef` to your command.  From openssl enc help:

```
-K/-iv         key/iv in hex is the next argument
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I generate this key using the openssl command line tool?

Comment: You can use the `rand` routine.